# plotting a quantitative variable against a list of strings in R

Tags: r, plot, label

I have the following data I would like to plot:

```
> x=c("X11", "X13", "X16", "X17")
> y=c(0.8, .9, .87, .84)
> foo=data.frame(x, y)
> foo
    x    y
1 X11 0.80
2 X13 0.90
3 X16 0.87
4 X17 0.84
```

I would like to get a plot where on the x axis I have the labels in the x column, and on the y axis I have the values in the y column. However, I get this:

[image: bad plot]

which is basically a box-plot in which I have only one observation for category. This won't do - for starters, I cannot change the plotting symbols, because they're not actually symbols, but degenerate boxes. If I change my data structure and go to named vectors, i.e.,

```
 > names(y)=x
 > y
  X11  X13  X16  X17 
  0.80 0.90 0.87 0.84 
 > plot(y)
```

I get this

[image: another bad plot]

where I'm now free to change the plot symbols, lines, colors, etc., but I cannot get the label names on the x axis. Aaargh!! It's so much easier in `matlab` or `python`, why must it be such a drag in `R`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plot without the x-axis and add it afterwards:

```
x=c("X11", "X13", "X16", "X17")
y=c(0.8, .9, .87, .84)
names(y)=x

plot(y, xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=1:4, labels = names(y))
```

[image]

Comment: All answers were good, and the other ones were one-liners, which in some respect is even better. But I choose this one because it's good to know that something like this is doable with base graphics. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Or with ggplot2:

```
ggplot(foo, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use qplot ( install package ggplot2 before using it.)

**qplot(foo$x,foo$y,data=foo)**